# Apple Watch receives notification, no haptic feedback

Tags: ios, watchkit

I made an Apple Watch app, and waited till I received my actual watch to test on a real device.

Today I finally got the chance to test my local notifications on my watch and all the time I receive a notification on my watch, but there is no actual haptic feedback giving me a presence of the notification. It is just silent.

My question, is this normal for notification in the testing phase or do you need to set it up as normal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It's just like the iPhone; you need to set the sound key in the push notification payload or it won't vibrate.

```
{
  "aps" : {
    "alert" : "You got your emails.",
    "badge" : 9,
    "sound" : "default"
}
```